# ODBC Error with Django Configuration - "Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'encrypt' "

Tags: python, sql-server, django

I have done quite a bit of searching on the error below and I have been hitting all around it, not finding where my configuration may be off.  When configuring django 3.x with a Microsoft SQL Server, I get the following error when running my application.  The error seems to point to some encryption parameter but in my testing, I have yet to determine which parameter.  I have tried a number of different security-based settings in the "OPTIONS" but no luck.   Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: ('08001', "[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid value specified for connection string attribute 'encrypt' (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Libraries installed

```
django-mssql-backend==2.8.1
pyodbc==4.0.30
```

Connection String

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME': 'testDB',
        'HOST': 'testserver.test.net',
        'PORT': '1433',
        'USER': 'username',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            'driver': 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server',
            'host_is_server': True,
            'connection_timeout': 30,
            'collation': 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS',
            'extra_params': 'Trusted_Connection=yes;Encrypt=yes',
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the documentation, that's correct... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?view=netframework-4.8